# What services does ServiceTracker find

Tags: java, osgi

Let's assume that we have two bundles - BundleA and BundleB. BundleA contains one service. BundleB contains ServiceTracker.

It seems to me, that ServiceTracker in bundleB will find service of BundleA only if bundleB is started before BundleA. By other words, ServiceTracker doesn't find services that were registered before ServiceTracker.open(). Is this right? P.S. I see this behavior on Apache Felix.

**EDIT**
As I was said that my statement was wrong here is my code. BundleA - pax-logging-service. In bundleB I have the following code:

```
public class PaxLoggingServiceCustomizer implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer<Object, Object>{

    private final BundleContext context;

    public PaxLoggingServiceCustomizer(BundleContext context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object addingService(ServiceReference<Object> reference) {
        System.out.println("# Service was added");
        ManagedService paxService = (ManagedService)context.getService(reference);
        return paxService;
    }

    @Override
    public void removedService(ServiceReference<Object> reference, Object service) {
    }

    @Override
    public void modifiedService(ServiceReference<Object> reference, Object service) {
        //do nothing
    }    

}
```

And this is bundleB activator

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private ServiceTracker serviceTracker;

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        String f = "(&(service.pid=org.ops4j.pax.logging)(objectClass=" + ManagedService.class.getName()+"))";
        Filter  filter=FrameworkUtil.createFilter(f);
        serviceTracker=new ServiceTracker(context,filter, new PaxLoggingServiceCustomizer(context));
        serviceTracker.open();
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        serviceTracker.close();
    }

}
```

When I start bundleB (mybundle) before bundleA (pax-logging-service) - everyhing works and service is added (I see `# Service was added` message). When I start bundleB (mybundle) after bundleA (pax-logging-service) - nothing works and service is never added (I don't see see `# Service was added` message even after one minute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. When you open a service tracker it will immediately see all services that are available in the service registry. If you suspect you are not seeing a service, even though it is registered, it might be because it's not visible to your bundle (because of how the bundles got resolved and wired in the framework).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I spent about hour trying to figure why bundleB doesn't find service of bundleA. At the same time bundleB found services of bundleC, bundleD etc. The problem was solved by changing order - when I started bundleB before bundleA. You can try.

Comment: @Pavel What Marcel said is absolutely correct. There must be something else wrong with your code -- you might need to post more details on what you are doing.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett No any hints?

Comment: @Pavel I can't see anything obvious wrong with your code. Just to test something, can you please change the activator to call `serviceTracker.open(true)` instead of just `serviceTracker.open()`. Please note this will NOT solve the problem but just give me information about what might be wrong.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett Thank you very much. ServiceTracker.open(true) helped. Now I can start BundleB after BundleA and everything works. Maybe you should make a answer?

Comment: @Pavel Okay we're half the way there. As I said this is NOT a solution, in fact it will break your code later. I think this means that your launcher code is bad... you should install all bundles before starting any bundle. Fix that then put back `ServiceTracker.open()`.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett It seems to me that I have to use open(true) because in bundleB I don't import any packages from bundleA (pax-logging-service) because there is no exported packages and for service interface I use quite different bundle. As I understand this is the reason why open(false) doesn't find bundleA. Am I right?

Comment: @Pavel Sorry but no. The problem is that you have multiple exports of the service interface package, and the consumer and provider are wiring to different exports. If you use open(true) then you will only get a ClassCastException later, so you need to fix the underlying issue.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett Thank you for your comment.Could you say 1) what you mean `have multiple exports of the service interface package` because I have only one package that exports `org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService`? 2) why I don't get any ClassCastException and everything works fine with open(true)?

Comment: 1) It's also possible that your consumer has it's own private copy of the service interface. 2) The CCE will occur when you call getService() on the tracker and try to cast it into a variable of the type you expect.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett Sorry for asking you but I don't understand. Three bundles: pax-logging-service, org.osgi.enterprice , mybundle. Mybundle has ServiceTracker to pax-logging-service with filter by `org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService`. I still can't find the reason why with open(true) mybundle finds pax-logging-service with open(false) doesn't.  In Mybunlde there is no any *.ManagedService and I don't see any *.ManagedService in pax-logging-service. What the private copy you are talking about?

Comment: @Pavel I don't think we are getting anywhere with this discussion. If you like, proceed with open(true) and when you get the ClassCastException later (which I still believe you will), open a new issue.